# unable to create excel data using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create an excel file and try to open it and perform some operations on that data.

```
file_path = 'd:/files/'
file_folder = 'new_files'
file_name = 'sample.xlsx'

def export(data):
    data.to_excel("{}/{}".format(downloadpath(), downloadfile()), index=False)
    excel_data = open("{}/{}".format(downloadpath(), downloadfile()), 'rb')
    # excel_data_operations

def downloadpath():
     PATH = os.path.join(file_path, file_folder)

     if not os.path.isdir(PATH):
         return os.makedirs(PATH)
    
     return PATH

def downloadfile():
    return file_name
```

I'm trying to do this, but getting end up with

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'None/sample.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of `downloadpath`:

- replace `return os.makedirs(PATH)`
- with `os.makedirs(PATH)`

Answer (score 0):

The string 'd:/files/' says that you use windows. In windows, the file path should use backslashes '\'.
Try to change the string to
d:\files\

Comment: I don't think its a / problem.

Comment: You return os.makedirs(PATH). This function returns None. This is definitely the problem

Comment: just remove 'return' before the 'os.makedirs(PATH)'